# Como ordenar en Bootstrap table campo fecha

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-table

Estoy usando bootstrap table y al ordenar por un campo donde el dato es fecha, no lo esta haciendo bien, creo que lo esta tratando como un `string`, los demás campos se ordenan perfectamente pero los que son de fecha no se ordenan.

Este es mi código de boostrap table

```
<table data-toggle="table" data-click-to-select="true" data-pagination="true" data-page-list="[5, 10, 15, 20]"
    data-height="340" data-search="true" class="table-hover table-responsive" id="tableRoomList">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-sortable="true">Date</th>
            <th data-sortable="true">Time</th>
            <th data-sortable="true">Type of Appointments</th>
            <th data-sortable="true">Doctor Name</th>
            <th data-sortable="true">Facility Name</th>
            <th data-sortable="true">Facility Address</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
        <tr>
            <td data-sortable="true">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TransDate)</td>
            <td data-field="record" data-sortable="true">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TimeIn)</td>
            <td data-sortable="true">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ApptType)</td>
            <td data-sortable="true">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DoctorName)</td>
            <td data-sortable="true">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FacilityName)</td>
            <td data-sortable="true">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FacilityAddress_1)</td>
        </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

El campo `TransDate` es una fecha y no se ordena correctamente como los demás

Comment: Bootstrap table solo puede ordenar strings.  Tienes dos opciones, colocar las fechas en formato yyyy-mm-dd o usar un plugin diferente como datatables.net

Comment: gracias alanfcm esa era la aclaracion que me hacia falta, entonces si no pongo la fecha en formato yyyy-mm-dd, deberia de quitar bootstrap table y usar jquery.DataTable?

Comment: Correcto @RaidelFonseca

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es que los datos se retornen ordenados, puedes ordenarlos en tu consulta a la base de datos.

Si los quieres ordenar después de que se carguen, puedes usar la librería 
[DataTables](https://datatables.net/) con jQuery. DataTables es un plugins aparte de Bootstrap Table.

Descarga el CSS de [aquí](https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.css) y el JS de [aquí](https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.js). A tu tabla ponle un id y en jQuery al iniciar coloca esto:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('id_tabla').DataTable();
});
```

Comment: quisiera que se ordenara cuando el usuario hace clic arriba de la tabla en el icono que tiene ya bootstrap table, usando bootstrap table puedo manejar el ordenamiento de esta columna fecha usando datatables con jquery ??

Comment: datatables es un plugins aparte de bootstrap table, ingresa en el enlace, ahi esta un ejemplo de datatables que ordena fecha en forma ascendente o descendente, pruebalo